# Scala macros, get methods by reflection

Tags: scala, macros

I need something like this:

```
object Macros {

  def check[T](f: T): Any = macro check_impl[T]

  def check_impl[T](c: Context)(f: c.Expr[Any]): c.Expr[T] = {

    import c.universe._

    //get all methods and if exist Method2 or Method4(need check methods recursively) println("OK")
  }

}

def test(....) = Macros.check {

  val x1 = Method1()

  val x2 = Method2()

  val x3 = Method3()
}



def method3(....) = {

  val x4 = Method4()

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Can you elaborate on exactly what you are trying to do?  I've edited your post to show the code properly, but we need you to edit it and add in more details on what you are trying to accomplish and what issues you are running into.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, through a macro I need to detect some methods.

Comment: What do you mean by "check methods recursively"?

Comment: I need to detect Method4, the only way to do is check recursively method test.